# Stress in negative words and flap "d" in "don't"

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

I've learned that negative words like *can't* or *don't* are stressed in sentences. However, I've heard native speakers pronouncing phrases like *I **don't** understand what's going on here*, where *don't* is pronounced very fast and lightly, like a flap *d*. Is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it happens.  Auxiliaries, including "do", are function words, and so can be unstressed, and before an unstressed vowel, intervocalic [d] can be flapped.  So after a vowel or diphthong, the [d] of "do[n't]" can be flapped.

Answer (score 0):

In casual register under little-understood conditions, /n/ flaps as well as /t/ and /d/. In American English, this can lead to the impossibility of distinguishing "I *can* understand" and "I *can't* understand".